# Entity Framework returning entities with null values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have my entity model in an assembly. The DAL and Repository layers are in separate assemblies. I use unit of work and repository pattern.

I set some properties of an entity to internal (both get & set), whilst all properties have internal get (this entity is just read-only).

When I do this and get a list of all records, the count is correct, however all properties are set to null or 0. When I set all properties' get/set to public, everything works fine.

Is it not possible to set getters/setters other than public when working across separate assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could mark the properties `internal` and use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to allow the assembly containing your entity model to access the properties. This would require the involved assemblies to be strong-named.

Comment: All assemblies are in the same solution therefore strong-named.